# Loading views in conrtroller using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. Can anybody explain to me how to load a view in a controller?

This is my controller:

```
<?php
    class Example extends CI_controller
    {
        function display($p,$p1)
        {
            echo $p1,$P;
            //here i want to load my view
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: So, there aren't any basic codeigniter tutorials out there? I find that hard to believe...

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html 

The Codeigniter user guide is filled with good working example and the community on IRC is always ready to help.

Comment: As @Musk suggested, please read an entire tutorial before jumping into SO for questions.

Comment: ok..i will check the documentation and then i will go for developing.. thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place fallowing code wherever you want to load the view

```
                 $this->load->view('viewname');
```

you can also pass the data to view as fallows

```
                 $data['key'] = 'this is data";\
                  $this->load->view('viewname',$data);
```

and also you did not mention $ symbol before 'p'